# Find all linear Fractional transformation that map $|z|<1$ onto $|w|<1$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, linear-fractional-transformation

Here is my attempted solution:
Let $f$ be a fractional linear transformation from $\mathbb D$ onto $\mathbb D$. Then $f$ is analytic.
Consider, $g= \phi_{f(0)} o f$.
Then $g$ maps $\mathbb D$ onto $\mathbb D$.
By Schwartz lemma, $|g^{-}(z)| \leq |z $ for all $z \in \mathbb D$.
So, $|g(z)|=|z|$ for all $z \in \mathbb D$.
Then, by 2nd part of Schwartz lemma, $g(z)=c_{1}z$ such that $|c_{1}=1|$ for all $z \in \mathbb D$.
So,
\begin{align}
     f(z) &=\phi_{f(0)}^{-1}(c_{1}z)\\ &= \frac{c_{1}z+\alpha_{1}}{1+ \alpha_{1}c_{1}z} \\ &=c_{1} \frac{z+ \bar{c_{1}} \alpha_{1}}{1+ \alpha_{1}c_{1}z}
    \end{align}

Here $\alpha_{1}=f(0)$ and  $|\bar{c_{1}}|=1$
Is my approach correct?

Comment: You need to explain your terminology, what is $\phi_{f(0)}?$ What is $g^-$???